# How do I slideUp and slideDown a group of <li />'s

Tags: jquery, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap's `list-group` classes to display a list of products under a few categories (images below). The user can click on a category to open it and close any others that are open (home-made accordion).

html:

```
<ul id="category_Reports" class="list-group category">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-heading">
        <a onclick="focusCategory('#category_Reports');">Reports</a>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item product">
        <i class="icon icon-40-mo1 pull-left"></i>
        <a class="btn btn-success pull-right" onclick="addProduct(MO1);">Add</a>
        Market Outlook 1
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>

    <li class="list-group-item product">...</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">...</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">...</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">...</li>
</ul>

<ul id="category_Newsletters" class="list-group category">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-heading">...</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">...</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">...</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">...</li>
</ul>

<ul id="category_Services" class="list-group category">
    <!--Services...-->
</ul>
```

js:

```
function focusCategory(id) {
    $('.category').not(id).children('.product').slideUp();
    $(id).children('.product').slideDown();
}
```

However, I am only targetting each `<li />` as a single unit when sliding up and down:

[image: current]

Is there a way to target all but the first `<li />` as a group so that it has a more coherent slideUp (and slideDown) animation?

[image: ideal]

It would be great if this could be accomplished without having to mess around with the existing bootstrap css.

Comment: You'll need to wrap them in a container, and the only valid containers for `<li>` are `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: Why not use [Bootstrap's collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)?

Comment: @Blazemonger Is there a way to wrap them inside another `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) while sticking to native bootstrap classes? Collapse is for a `<div class="panel-body">`, which wouldn't allow for the list items (at least not without fussing with css to remove padding and such). My goal here (which my be impractical) is to do everything without having to go hacking around with the bootstrap css

Comment: Sorry, not really. As far as I can tell, it's either hack away or remove the sliding animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want will require wrapping all the `li` elements to be collapsed into a single container, and the only valid containers are `ol` and `ul`. So your current HTML structure won't be able to do what you want.

You'll have to do a little hacking, but you can do it by adding your own CSS without altering Bootstrap's.

First, divide up your lists into two more, and add your own classes -- I called them `list-group-top` and `list-group-bottom`:

```
<ul id="category_Newsletters" class="list-group category list-group-top">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-heading"><a onclick="focusCategory('#category_Newsletters');">Heading</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group category list-group-bottom"> <!-- note the repeated classes -->
    <li class="list-group-item product">item 1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">item 2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item product">item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Now, add some overriding styles -- make sure these are loaded *after* Bootstrap's CSS file:

```
.list-group-top {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.list-group-bottom+.list-group-top {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.list-group-top .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.list-group-bottom .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
}
```

Finally a short tweak to your JavaScript to accommodate the new DOM tree:

```
function focusCategory(id) {
    $('.category').not(id).next('.list-group-bottom').slideUp();
    $(id).next('.list-group-bottom').slideDown();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/32q6a/

Alternatively, instead of using `slideUp` and `slideDown`, you could add and remove classes to the `.list-group-top` container and add CSS animations. This would give you a little more power to style the lists in their "collapsed" state.